# Best way to query 2 different keywords from different lines following a pattern in a file

Tags: linux, unix, redhat, aix

I have a log from which I need to get few lines by performing some form of search. The log entry I am looking for is shown below, in which I am looking for keywords "Delete" and "CN=USERNAME".

What is the best way to do it in aix 7.1 and rhel 6

AuditV3--2017-01-24T19:06:27.365000-5:00--V3 Delete--bindDN: cn=root--client: 192.160.0.120:6000--connectionID: 17232--received: 2017-01-24T19:06:27.360000-5:00--Success
operationResponseTime: 5
timeOnWorkQ: 0
rdbmLockWaitTime: 0
clientIOTime: 0
controlType: 1.3.6.1.4.1.42.2.27.8.5.1
criticality: false
controlType: 1.3.18.0.2.10.32
criticality: false
entry: CN=USERNAME,OU=PEOPLE,DC=COMPANY,DC=COM

Comment: Why not simply use `grep`?

Comment: How can I ?. The stanza which I mentioned has new lines in it. I need the whole stanza with or without new lines/spaces

Comment: Then said exactly what you need. What is the limit of your stanza? If you cannot specify it, I cannot guess it :-(

Comment: It has 10 lines total. I just used grep with -A option and got the result like this " cat file.log | grep -A10 AuditV3 | grep -A10 Delete"     It did the trick